# Django - Remove "Currently" In An Image Edit Form and Replace It With The Actual Image

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When editing an object that has an image field, you are presented with the current image path and the standard file upload field. What I want to do is to be able to replace the shown path(the "Currently: /pathtoimage.jpg" with the actual image. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a ModelForm or a custom form? If you have the path, why can't you just tweak the template to render the image with <img src="{{ path }}" />?

Comment: yes I can do that, but I want to remove that "Currently: <path here>" showing up. Can I do this with a tweaked template?

Comment: if you know how to do it with a tweaked one, just put it in the answer. sorry if I missed something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about a form in Django's admin you could override the AdminImageWidget.

There are few snippets and posts that explain the details:

- [Django simple admin ImageField thumbnail](http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/06/20/django-simple-admin-imagefield-thumbnail/)
- [ImageField for admin with thumbnail](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1580/)
- [Admin Image Widget](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/934/)

For regular forms you should take a look at [django-form-utils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-form-utils):

> This application provides utilities
> for enhancing Django's form handling:
>
> An ImageWidget which display a thumbnail of the image rather than
> just the filename.

Comment: it supports thumbnailing only with sorl. sigh, I use django-imagekit T_T

Comment: Oh :-) But i would assume that it's not to hard to swap sorl with your solution. Or as your only interested in the ImageWidget your could try to write your own (using another thunbail lib) based on the existing code: https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils/blob/master/form_utils/widgets.py

Comment: I just copied that code and boy was it easy to override that default imagefield widget. XD