# Deleting individual related files - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django modelformset which does the following:

**Add page**

- Add model instance for 'product'
- Model related (ForeignKey) to
  'product' for adding multiple  pictures to the product instance.

**Edit Page**

- The formset is also on an editing page, it is pre-populated with the 'product' instance and its related images.

**Here's the problem**, when I upload multiple images to a product, I want to be able to delete selected images from the edit page (keep the rest).

**How can I pass the individual image - its location in the database, and its location on the filesystem, to some kind of delete method?** In an ideal world I would like achieve this by some kind of AJAX method, but where can I start?

*View for editing...*

```
def EditProduct(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductImage,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=4)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = AddEditProductForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                        queryset=ProductImage.objects.none())

        if product_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

            product = product_form.save()

            images = formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.product = product
                image.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/product/')

        else:
            print (product_form.errors, formset.errors)

    else:
        product_form = AddEditProductForm(instance=instance)
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=ProductImage.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'product/edit.html',
                  {'product_form': product_form, 'formset': formset},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**A minor thing** - How can I actually display, in the template, the images that are already uploaded to the product? Currently the images just display as pre-populated extra instances of the formset (url to image file).

*template for editing...*

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table> 
            <p> {{ product_form.as_ul }}</p>

                <p> current images </p>     

                {% for product in product.images.all %}
                <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="...">
                {% endfor %}
                <br> <p> break </p>

            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form }}
            {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Changes">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I found a [way to delete individual images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824958/how-to-delete-an-image-using-django) by using a custom function.

If you want to display the images related to a product, there are a couple of ways I found: one way is to [modify the FileField widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722899/django-remove-currently-in-an-image-edit-form-and-replace-it-with-the-actual) if you want to display the images in the form...

What I did instead was remove the uploaded images that prepopulated the form by changing the second queryset to`queryset=ProductImage.objects.none())`, then I added `pictures = ProductImage.objects.filter(product_id = pk)` to the view  and then looped through them in the template.

Hopefully this helps somebody.